# Return item when finished in Angular/Ionic

Tags: angularfire2

I want to get id of added entity, but it returns nothing since this entity is not added yet. How can I call this service function and wait until it will not be finished?

```js
 //Service file
 AddItem(data, downloadURLs) {
    data.upload = downloadURLs;

    // Add a new document with a generated id
    var addDoc = this.db.collection('items').add(data).then(ref => {
      var updateNested = this.db.collection('items').doc(ref.id).update({
        id: ref.id
      });
    });
  }
  
  //Here I call it
  onAddItem() {
    if (this.AddItemForm.valid) {
      var result = this.itemService.AddItem(this.AddItemForm.value, this.uploadService.downloadURLs);
    }
  }
```

Comment: In this example I'm not returning anything, since I tried a lot of methods to do it. I can't move further because of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test my code snippet but I'm guessing this might work for you.
Just wrap your calls to db (returning promises) with async await. In my example the addItem method returns a promise containing your added item.

```
//Service file
async addItem(data, downloadURLs) {
   data.upload = downloadURLs;

  // Add a new document with a generated id
  const ref = await this.db.collection('items').add(data);
  const item = await this.db.collection('items').doc(ref.id).update({ id: ref.id });

 return item;
}

//Here I call it
async onAddItem() {
  if (this.AddItemForm.valid) {
  const item = await this.addItem(this.value, this.uploadService.downloadURLs);
  //do something with the item here
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that const item will hold the ID? I checked it right now and it returns "undefined".

Comment: Could you prepare a running code sample so I can edit this directly? Otherwise you could add another call in the add item method to retrieve the added item and return this instead. I thought the update method would return a promise containing the updated item.

Something like 
return await this.db.get(ref.id)